# Factorial and product series

Tags: factorial, products

Help me prove this equation is right

$$n!=\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}-k\right)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2k}-1\right)}$$

[Desmos Link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/znwlloflfl)

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question)

Comment: I Fixed and Updated

Comment: I think your question should be: Prove that for $n=6$ the following is true:$$n!=...$$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as

$$\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}-k\right)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2k}-1\right)}$$

$$=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}-(k-1)\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{2k}-1\right)}$$

This simplifies to

$$=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(\frac{1-2k}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-2k}{2k}\right)}$$

$$=\prod_{k=1}^n\ k$$

Comment: We should not answer such "no-effort" questions.

Comment: @AnneBauval; OP includes a working Desmos link.

Comment: This useless link cannot seriously be considered as an attempt of proof.